# This if statement is adding itself to the next row

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

[image: Image showing row issue]

This is adding the previous rows rating query every time a new row is displayed any ideas as to why its doing this? Have I failed to close the loop in some way?

Please help I have limited SQL, IF statement knowledge and it has been ruining my mind for days now

```
    <?php
                // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT sailors.id, sailors.habbo, ranks.rank, ranks.abv, rating.ratingabv, rating.rating, position.position 
        FROM (((sailors 
            INNER JOIN ranks ON sailors.rankid = ranks.rankid) 
                INNER JOIN rating ON sailors.ratingid = rating.ratingid)        
                    INNER JOIN position ON sailors.pos_id = position.pos_id)    
        WHERE sailors.rankid=30";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     echo"<div class='col-md-12'> <h1>W-5 Chief Warrant Officer Five (CWO5)</h1></div>";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $ast_query = $conn->query("select ast_list.ast_tag from (ast_list INNER JOIN ast ON ast.ast_id = ast_list.ast_id) where ast_sailor_id = '" . $row['id'] . "'");
        $str_ast = '';

        $last_promo = $conn->query("select promo.date, sailors.habbo, promo.promo_officer_id, sailors.id FROM (promo INNER JOIN sailors ON sailors.id = promo.promo_officer_id) WHERE promo_sailor_id = '" . $row['id'] . "' ORDER BY promoid DESC LIMIT 1");
        $str_promo = '';

        $last_promo3 = $conn->query("select promo.date, sailors.habbo, promo.promo_officer_id, sailors.id FROM (promo INNER JOIN sailors ON sailors.id = promo.promo_officer_id) WHERE promo_sailor_id = '" . $row['id'] . "' ORDER BY promoid DESC LIMIT 1");
        $str_promo3 = '';

        $last_promodate = $conn->query("select promo.date, sailors.habbo FROM (promo INNER JOIN sailors ON sailors.id = promo.promo_officer_id) WHERE promo_sailor_id = '" . $row['id'] . "' ORDER BY promoid DESC LIMIT 1");
        $str_promo2 = '';

        $rating_query = $conn->query("SELECT sailors.id, sailors.habbo, ranks.rank, ranks.abv, rating.ratingabv, rating.rating, position.positionabv, position.position FROM (((sailors INNER JOIN ranks ON sailors.rankid = ranks.rankid) INNER JOIN rating ON sailors.ratingid = rating.ratingid) INNER JOIN position ON sailors.pos_id = position.pos_id) WHERE sailors.id = '" . $row['id'] . "'");
        $str_rating = '';

        while($promo_array = $last_promo->fetch_assoc()){
            $str_promo .= $promo_array['habbo'];
        }
        while($promo_array2 = $last_promo3->fetch_assoc()){
            $str_promo3 .= $promo_array2['id'];
        }

        while($promo_array2 = $last_promodate->fetch_assoc()){
            $str_promo2 .= $promo_array2['date'];
        }

        while($ast_array = $ast_query->fetch_assoc()){
            $str_ast .= $ast_array['ast_tag'];
        }
        if ($ast_query->num_rows > 0) {
            $text  = "(" . $str_ast . ")";
        } else { 
            $text = "";
        } 

        while($rating_array = $rating_query->fetch_assoc()){
            $str_position .= $rating_array['positionabv'];
        }

        if ($row['position'] == "None"){
            $rating  = "". $row["ratingabv"]. "";
        } else { 

            $rating = "/" . $str_position . "";
        } 


        echo " 
        <div class='col-md-4'><div class='panel panel-default'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h4 class='text-white'><center><b>". $row["habbo"]. "</b></center></h4>
        </div>

        <div class='panel-body'>
        <center>
        <a href='sailor.php?id=". $row["id"] ."'>
            <img class='img-responsive'  src='https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=". $row["habbo"]. "&direction=2' alt=''>
            </a></center><br>
            <center><p><b>USN: " . $row["abv"] . "" . $rating . "




            " . $text . "</b>

            <center><small>Last promoted by <a href='sailor.php?id=". $str_promo3 ."'>" . $str_promo . "</a> <br>  " . $str_promo2 . "</small></center>
                 <p></center>

            </div>
        </div></div> ";

     }
} else {
     echo "";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you never reset `$str_position`? So this has nothing to do with sql or `if`... you just keep piling more and more food on your plate every time you go to the buffet, without ever "eating" it...

Comment: What would be the best way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Put `$str_position = "";` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Or right before the `while($rating_array = ...)` loop.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to nest multiple joins in parentheses like that. Just `SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON ... JOIN table3 ON ...`

Comment: Legend, Thank you so much what do I need to revise to improve this code further or is it all pretty much okay except that issue?